# GCP subnetworks.listUsable does not return shared subnets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-vpc

I have a Shared VPC setup between 2 projects - Shared VPC Host Project P1 and Shared VPC Service Project P2. The host project P1 shares certain subnets with P2, which I can see on the console. I have Owner, Service Networking Admin and Compute Network User roles on the Host project and Owner and Service Networking Admin roles on the Service project.

I am trying to call this API on service project P2

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/subnetworks/listUsable

"Retrieves an aggregated list of all usable subnetworks in the project. The list contains all of the subnetworks in the project and the subnetworks that were shared by a Shared VPC host project"

This API only returns all the subnets that were created in project P2 and none of the shared subnets. The gcloud equivalent "gcloud compute networks subnets list-usable" does the same thing.

How do I get the list of subnets shared with a given project?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/provisioning-shared-vpc#discovering_subnets_that_can_be_used), the following flag `--project HOST_PROJECT_ID` is necessary to list the usable subnets of a shared VPC from the service project.

Steps:

1) `$ gcloud compute networks subnets list-usable --project bejoy-test-waw --format=json`

2) `Find the appropriate <matching subnetwork> from the resulting list`

3) `$ gcloud compute networks subnets list-usable --project bejoy-test-waw --filter="subnetwork:<matching subnetwork>"` 
I hope this information helps!

Best regards,

Comment: Actually, this returns all the subnets in that project, not just the ones shared. For example, if I specify any other project's id, not part of a Shared VPC, it returns all the subnets in the project. What I am looking for is only the shared subnets.

Comment: Hello @Aiswarya Bhavanishankar, seems that what you're are trying to achieve is not implemented yet. I've found an [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/123976351) to implement this feature. Feel free to comment on it. I suggest you to add it to favorites in order to track its process.

Comment: After performing some tests, I've managed to find out how to solve check the usable subnets of a shared VPC. Answer edited.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I am not able to fetch only shared VPC from host project or service project? Which property distinguishes regular VPC vs shared VPC?