# Rest API to fetch shared VPC from service project in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have added service project and using below API, I am figuring out the host project
GET [https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{project}/getXpnHost](https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/%7Bproject%7D/getXpnHost)

Now, I need to fetch all shared VPCs so that I can use in service project. I am not able to find rest API that can give me list of shared VPCs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You specified the correct API. What problem do you have using it?

Comment: That API only gives me host project. I want to get shared VPCs

Comment: Without details, my guess is you do not have permission. Improve your question with more details.

Comment: I have permissions. When I execute below API on host project, it gives me all networks. There is no way to know which one is shared VPC.
https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/host-project/aggregated/subnetworks/listUsable
I want to fetch only shared VPCs

Comment: Your question has no code, no details, no error messages, and no results. Nothing for us to help you with. Read these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @user1302064 Does this API[1] help?
[1]: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/listXpnHosts

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57366736/gcp-subnetworks-listusable-does-not-return-shared-subnets?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You may also try the `listXpnHosts` [API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/listXpnHosts) that lists all shared VPC host projects visible to the user in an organization.

You may also check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/apis) for other useful APIs related to Google VPC Networks.

Answer (score 0):

This question hits upon a great irony of Subnetworks & Shared VPC in GCP: technically, both operate at the *project* level (not network).  As such, sharing a "VPC network" actually means sharing one or more subnets attached to that network.

To verify Shared VPC network permissions, this is how I do it:

1. Given the service project ID, get the Host Project ID via [projects.getXpnHost()](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/getXpnHost)
2. For that Host Project ID, get all networks via [networks.list()](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/networks/list)
3. Each network will have a list of subnet URLs.  To check if the service project has permission on each subnet, use [subnetworks.getIamPolicy](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/subnetworks/getIamPolicy) and verify the bindings list includes the service project's default service account, and have the `compute.networkUser` role.

The default service account for the service project can be retrieved via [projects.get()](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/get), and should be `<PROJECT_NUMBER>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`